# margin-right does not work on relative element? (width 100%)

Tags: html, css

My problem currently is, that `margin-right` does not work anymore with `width: 100%`.

I already tried leaving the `width: 100%` off, changing the position etc.
but nothing works. All questions I've saw in the internet and the answers hasn't helped me out. I tried so much. Does it actual work without `width: 95%` and stuff like that? Did I miss something?

```html
<body>
    <div class="content" id="id_content">
      <div class="topbar-header">
        <input type="text" class="topbar-field" style="min-width: 300px; max-width: 600px; width: 30%;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

```css
/* The header to search and navigate on. */
.topbar-header {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--val-head-height);
  background-color: var(--color-menu-background);
}
```

This happens [here,](http://prntscr.com/oi2nu8)
but I want space from right.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: When applying width: 100% it means that the container take the whole width, so margin right (nor left) is not something that will work here. You can either minimize the width or use the padding property instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can use `width: calc(100% - value)` or just set padding of the parrent (`.content { padding-right: 32px; }`)

```css
/* The header to search and navigate on. */
.topbar-header {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% - 64px);
  height: 48px;
  margin-right: 256px;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="content" id="id_content">
    <div class="topbar-header">
      <input type="text" class="topbar-field" style="min-width: 300px; max-width: 600px; width: 30%;">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```